# Data.com clean - setup

Tags: data.com, cleanup

I am new to Admin stuffs and trying to setup data.com clean-up some imported lead and account information in the system. What do I need to do in order to implement do I need to install any package in order to do that? I have "Enterprise edition"

Comment: funny - I just did a Clean setup last week.  You need a [Data.com Clean license](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_dot_com_clean_clean_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Comment: yes i do have clean license and my org is enterprise edition and i just need to know how to setup and working example.

Comment: Nick - this is covered exhaustively here:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_dot_com_clean_implementing.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.17 - just follow all the steps